# object saved as binary in couchbase

Tags: java, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I am using ‘MappingCouchbaseConverter’ from spring library like below

```
CouchbaseDocument target = new CouchbaseDocument();
mappingCouchbaseConverter.write(myObject, target);
ctx.insert(couchbaseClientFactory.getCollection(
“mybucketName”).reactive(), null, target.getContent());
```

I am using transactions.

above code writes a binary data insteed of JSON, can anyone please help, how can I write the Json insteed of binary object

Comment: What version of Spring Data Couchbase?

Comment: using version 6.6

Comment: Can you double check? I'm pretty sure the latest version of Spring Data Couchbase is 4.1.7  https://search.maven.org/search?q=spring%20data%20couchbase